# Unable to import JS library to .html document

Tags: javascript, java, html, intellij-idea, javascript-import

I would be gratefull you for your help:

I am trying to import js library and getting this error:

[image]

Tried to download library by click on Yellow lamp and get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first screen is just a warning that your IDE cannot autocomplete or navigate to symbols unless it had downloaded the library locally.

The second one indicates a certificate error during download, which often happens behind (corporate) firewalls which replace certificates in order to inspect SSL traffic. This replacement seems to not pass the validity check of your IDE's (because it doesn't include the requested hostname, silently accepting such certificates would enable man-in-the-middle attacks). Either there is an option in your IDE to (temporarily) reduce SSL security, or the proxy needs a fix.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I thought that js not working due to this error, but i found another issue and fixed it. So, this error not affecting to js. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience. those links should work without any problem. I think it's just your editor that highlights it as an error. but your page should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for explaining, I thought that js not working due to this error, but i found another issue and fixed it. So, this error not affecting to js. Thanks to all